# want to send value into cmd, dont know the command or how

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd

ok, i have a compiled .exe file that ask for a URL and when i prompt in http-link it tells me the title of the website, feels like a small and simple script so i wanted to loop through a list of websites using this .exe file so i tried first using a batch file. But it seems to be difficult to pass through links, so i tried powershell cause i read somewhere it should be easier if i used keystrokes but ended up with java to make it easy. However, i dont understand how i can "send" the link from the list into the compiled .exe file while running. This is how i draw it first time...

```
-> start bat-program.
-> ->call for start .exe file 
-> ->wait 2sec or when ready.
-> ->send URL into .exe 
-> ->press enter command
-> ->wait 2sec
-> ->press exit command
-> ->wait 2sec
-> loop....
```

i been able to start/loop the program within cmd or powershell with bat or java but not sending the values when the application is running.. feel kinda stupid :(

thanks for any suggestion how i can get it to work...

Comment: What do you mean by send value/URL? Is that like stdin or keyboard input when you run the exe from cmd?

Comment: Post your batch file and your java source.

Comment: i start program via cmd, enter value is like "http://www.google.com/"
when i press enter and get "Google" 
So not sure what you mean with stdin or keyboard input.... :-( *reading about stdin for the moment*

Comment: Could you please write in proper English with correct spelling, punctuation and capitalisation? This is not a chat site!

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class Wrapper {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
            for (String url : Arrays.asList("google.com/", "github.com/")) {
                Process process = new ProcessBuilder("compiled.exe").start();

                //process stdin / stderr streams asynchronously.
                executor.submit(() -> {
                    readStream((String s) -> System.out.println("STDOUT::" + s), process.getInputStream());
                });
                executor.submit(() -> {
                    readStream((String s) -> System.out.println("STDERR::" + s), process.getErrorStream());
                });

                Thread.sleep(2000);//wait 2 sec
                provideCommandInput(process, url);//url with enter
                Thread.sleep(2000);//wait 2 sec
                provideCommandInput(process, "exit");//exit with enter            
                Thread.sleep(2000);//wait 2 sec

                process.destroy();
            }
            executor.shutdown();
        }

        //Read a stream
        public static void readStream(Consumer<String> lineConsumer, InputStream is) {
            try (BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))) {
                buffer.lines().forEach(lineConsumer);
            } catch (UncheckedIOException | IOException ex) {
                //broken pipe.
            }
        }

        //provide input to the given process
        private static void provideCommandInput(Process proc, String command) throws IOException {
            final String newline = System.lineSeparator();
            proc.getOutputStream().write((command + newline).getBytes());
            proc.getOutputStream().flush();
        }
    }
```